# ReactNative Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: react-native

**my ./src/context/index.js**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    const MyContext = React.createContext;

    class MyProvider extends Component {
       state = {
           stage: 1,
          players: [],
          result: ''
       }

    render(){
        return(

            <>
                <MyContext.Provider value={{
                    state: this.state
                }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </MyContext.Provider>    
            </>
        )
    }
}

     export{MyProvider, MyContext}
```

**my ./Project/intext**

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {MyProvider} from './src/context'

const provider = () => (

    <MyProvider>
        <App/>
    </MyProvider>
  
 )

 AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => provider);
```

im using `export {provider}` whith `import{provider} from 'path'` as i have seen from  other question i realize the bracket mistake is common. In my case i can not locate what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot the paranthesis for the function call.

It should be: const MyContext = React.createContext();

Comment: that was it ! Thnx A lot